# Draw inside a win32 HRGN object

Tags: winapi

I am implementing a border control in win32, and I have implemented various styles for that border. I am using simple MoveTo() and LineTo() commands for drawing the border.
My problem is, when i select some new style for my border, it starts painting over the currently drawn border. I understand i need to refresh/repaint my window inorder to have a fresh canvas. I am using InvalidateRect() for now to achieve this purpose. But I am concerned, If i have other windows associated with my border control window (as child windows), how will this effect the child windows?i will need to repaint everything on this window, correct?

Secondly, Is there anyway I can draw lines inside a GDI Region (HRGN)? So far, all i have come across is how to fill up that HRGN with some fill color. Is there anyway i can retrieve HDC associated with that particular HRGN object??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a concern, anything you draw is automatically clipped by the child window rectangles.  No extra code is required.  The underlying window style flag is WS_CLIPCHILDREN.

You cannot draw lines in a region nor are they associated with a device context.  Other than by drawing the region and then drawing the lines in your paint message handler.  You are probably interested in paths.  The MSDN docs [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183316%28v=vs.85%29).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the pointer to Paths objects, i dont think i'l need to use them though. I just wanted to be sure about the repainting of my child windows attached to my parent border window. Thanks!